# Returning default value in method if there are no matches

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a method that will find an operator and return the new position.

```
public Integer findToken(Character operator) {
    try {
        return tokenList.stream()
                .filter(x -> {
                    return x.position >= startPosition &&
                            x.position <= endPosition &&
                            x.operator == operator;
                })
                .findFirst().get()
                .position;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

But if there are no matches, i want it to keep the old value.

```
startPosition = findToken(Operator.value);
```

How do i return the old value ? i tried giving a new parameter with the value in the method and passing it in the exception but then the code looks ugly. Is there a better way ?

Comment: You should NOT be using Optional.get() unless you can prove that there is a match (e.g., isPresent() has already returned true).  You should use one of the safe methods, orElse, orElseThrow, ifPresent, etc.  Here, you can just condition off isPresent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Doing the assignment that way, it is not possible unless you pass the old value as parameter.

What you can do is to change the assignment to use the `Optional` to take care of the `null` case:

```
Optional.ofNullable(findToken('*'))
        .ifPresent(pos -> startPosition = pos);
```

Also, it would probability make more sense to use the `Optional` to make it more explicit that the method `findToken` may not return a value:

```
public Optional<Integer> findToken(Character operator) {
    return tokenList.stream()
            .filter(x ->
                 x.position >= startPosition &&
                 x.position <= endPosition &&
                 x.operator == operator
            )
            .findFirst()
            .map(t -> t.position);
}
```

In such case, the assignment would be:

```
findToken('*').ifPresent(pos -> startPosition = pos);
```

Answer (score 5):

You may want to use **orElse()** method.
 Store the result till **findFirst** in temporary variable and then perform other operations and return.
For Instance

```
    List<Integer> values = Arrays.asList(2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1); 
    Integer i= values.stream()
                     .filter(x->x<1)
                     .findFirst().orElse(0);

    System.out.println(i);
```